# Storing boost_shared pointers in a vector - Is it expensive

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I know that vectors tend to make a copy of all objects pushed into them. My question is whether it would make sense to store a pointer to a `boost::shared_ptr` in a vector rather than the shared ptr itself

Comment: test it? vs a c style array of pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only 100% correct answer to any performance questions is "profile and see."

However, in this particular case, you should just keep the `shared_ptr`s in there directly (by value). The overhead of copying a shared pointer is low. And if your compiler supports moves, it will even be moved instead - although then you'd probably be using `std::shared_ptr`, right?

How would you do it to store just pointers in there, anyway? Allocate the `shared_ptr`s dynamically? How would you control their own ownership?

Comment: maybe he has the shared_ptrs already stored somwhere else - nut guaranteeing that they don't run out of scope while they are stored in the vector would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

shared_ptr are meant to manage the life-time of raw pointers. Storing and accessing them thru containers is hardly an overhead. If you store a pointer to shared_ptr into a container then you would defeat the whole purpose of shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ask about "expensive"? Your first concern apart from correctness should be "is it safe". Your second concern should be "is it readable and maintainable". Cost only is in the top 5 of your concerns if you know (by profiling) that you are working in a performance sensitive area. And even then there's "safety first" in almost every case.

So:

- don't use pointers to `shared_ptr`, because it's hard to get that safe and correct.
- don't use pointers to `shared_ptr`, because it's brittle, hard to descipher and makes everyone wonder why you did that (maintainability)
- don't use pointers to `shared_ptr` *unless* you really know that copying the `shared_ptr`s is a performance issue, and you know by profiling *and you don't have other, safer, more maintainable and equally performant solutions*

**tl;dr** don't use pointers to `shared_ptr`.